# How to configure video mixing in Restcomm

Tags: webrtc, sip, voip, restcomm

I try to create conference call using Olympus provided by Restcomm-Connect. Sound is OK, but video is no available. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video is not yet available and currently being worked on, see https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/issues/1895. Let us know if you want to contribute to the effort. any help would be highly appreciated